# Not able to close a sliding-over modal

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a modified version of the codrops slide & push menu (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/) to get an overlay on a webpage. But i'm not able to close it again with another link.
Any help would be appreciated.
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qu80jto2/

HTML:

```
<nav class="modal modal-vertical modal-right" id="modal">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
</nav>

<h1 id="showRight">OPEN</h1>
<h1 id="hideRight">CLOSE</h1>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script>
    var 
        menuRight = document.getElementById( 'modal' ),
        body = document.body;

    showRight.onclick = function() {
        classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
        classie.toggle( menuRight, 'modal-open' );
        disableOther( 'showRight' );
    };

    function disableOther( button ) {
        if( button !== 'showRight' ) {
            classie.toggle( showRight, 'disabled' );
        }
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed;
}

.modal-vertical {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.modal-right {
    right: -60%;
}

.modal-open {
    right: 0px;
}

.modal-push {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

.modal,
.modal-push {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
<nav class="modal modal-vertical modal-right" id="modal">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
        </nav>

        <h1 id="showRight">OPEN</h1>
        <h1 id="hideRight">CLOSE</h1>

        <script>
            var 
                menuRight = document.getElementById( 'modal' ),
                body = document.body;


            showRight.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuRight, 'modal-open' );
                disableOther( 'showRight' );
            };

            function disableOther( button ) {
                if( button !== 'showRight' ) {
                    classie.toggle( showRight, 'disabled' );
                }
            }

            hideRight.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuRight, 'modal-open' );
                disableOther( 'hideRight' );
            };

            function disableOther( button ) {
                if( button !== 'hideRight' ) {
                    classie.toggle( hideRight, 'disabled' );
                }
            }
        </script>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/qu80jto2/1/)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Would there also be a way to close the modal on pressing the escape key in this scenario?

Comment: the escape key doesn't seem to get triggered in this fiddle @ivin-raj

Comment: wait sir i will do it @kreemers

Comment: any luck yet? @ivin-raj

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you want to **open** OR **slide-in** the overlay when you click on **Open** and **close** OR **slide-out** when you click on **Close**.

Then this will do the trick for you as:

```
        showRight.onclick = function() {
            classie.removeClass(hideRight, 'active');
            classie.addClass(this, 'active');
            classie.addClass(menuRight, 'modal-open');
            disableOther('showRight');
        };
        hideRight.onclick = function() {
            classie.removeClass(showRight, 'active');
            classie.addClass(this, 'active');
            classie.removeClass(menuRight, 'modal-open');
            disableOther('hideRight');
        };
```

Here's a working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/qu80jto2/3/)